# Issues finding Thorlab device using pyserial on a mac running high-sierra.

Tags: python, interface, ftdi

I am trying to modify a package called thorpy in order to communicate with a a **FTDI device** sold by Thorlab. The device is an **APT TDC001 T-Cube** which use a USB and an RS-232 interface. I would like to know the *best way to send and receive communication with a device like this one*. What are some of the considerations one must take into account when trying to establish communication with a usb device from a proprietary vendor. The vendor provides a pdf intended to help in the creation of new interfaces. Any help will be appreciated. I am not an expert with python, but I have a strong background in programming. Thank you in advance.